# How can I retrieve a list of SQL Server LocalDb names?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, localdb

I am using Entity Framework with SQL Server LocalDb as a storage medium for my application. I need to find a way to switch between different databases that have the same SQL structure.

My idea is to do this from the DbContext:

```
public const bool RecreateDB = false;

public UnifiedContext() : this(RecreateDB) { }
public UnifiedContext(bool recreateDb):this(recreateDb, "DemoDB") { }

public UnifiedContext(bool recreateDB, string dbName) : base($"MyUniquePrefix.{dbName}")
{
    if (recreateDB)
        Database.SetInitializer(new DropCreateDatabaseAlways<UnifiedContext>());
    else
        Database.SetInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<UnifiedContext, UnifiedConfiguration>());
}
```

This works fine just like I want it to. However I now need to display a list of LocalDbs for loading I know I can get a list of SQL databases with `System.Data.Sql.SqlDataSourceEnumerator.Instance.GetDataSources();` but that doesn't work for LocalDbs.

How can I retrieve a list of LocalDb names?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since LocalDb is for Developers and not for Database-Administrators, the Databases are stored in a folder.

Usually this folder is

> C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server Local
>   DB\Instances\MSSQLLocalDB

Each file ending with .mdf is an DataBase.

Unfortunately there is - afaik- no built in mechanic to enlist them, since localDb is file based and you are able to save it whereever **you** want.

Comment: Excellent thanks... It appears that my files are just being stored in `C:\Users\username\` folder; but this puts me on the right path.

Answer (score 3):

You can connect to the master database, and run:

```
SELECT name FROM sys.databases
```